# How to manipulate with SDL Media Manager items from core service?

Tags: 2013, core-service, ecl, media-manager

I have to get some information about media items from SDL Media Manager in my core service.

I found this [article](http://philipmedcraft.blogspot.rs/2017/03/connecting-to-sdl-media-manager.html) but I coudn't make connection to MM.

I add service reference (MediaManager2011.svc) to my solution but I still don't have IMediaManager2011Client.

Is there some other way to get this informations from MM in service?

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to get?

Comment: Please share more information regarding your solution. Are you using .Net for example? Do you have a working Secure Token Service?

Comment: I use .Net and I have working Secure Token Service. I also have valid certificate. I supose that I have to add it to app.config in system.ServiceModel to customBinding but I didn't come to that part jet.

Answer (score 6):

I have updated the [following article](http://philipmedcraft.blogspot.com.br/2017/03/connecting-to-sdl-media-manager.html). It now contains an extract of the App.config file containing the bindings and endpoint information.

Configure your App.config file with the URL to your Secure Token Service and you should be able to connect to SDL Media Manager using the provided helper class.

```
var mediaManagerClient = MediaManagerHelper.GetMediaManagerClient();
```

Comment: I update my app.config but I cannot find Secure Token Service address. Could you please help me and tell me where should I look for that address?

Comment: In an earlier comment, you confirmed having a working Secure Token Service. This should be available from an endpoint URL. Do you know who set up this web service on your side? Please request the details and update the app.config accordingly.

Comment: I wrote that i have working STS, because I have installed Media Manager and it works.
I'm not totally sure, but I think that Media Manager is installed by SDL Professional Service.

Comment: You need your own Secure Token Service in order to provide authentication tokens to your Media Manager client. When setting up the STS, you can try applying the same certificate used by Media Manager's connector in SDL Web (Tridion).

Comment: I have difficulties in creating STS, do you have any source or example for that?